# AJAX Call is not working in Mozilla Firefox Browser Mac OS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, macos, firefox

Rails 4 + AJAX Call + Mac OS + Mozilla

```
_header.html.erb

    <span class="callno"><%= link_to "Sign in", {:controller => "web",:action => "sign_in_user"}, :role => 'button', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#popup_div', :remote => true %></span>

web_controller.rb

   def sign_in_user
     binding.pry
   end

routes.rb
 get '/web/sign_in_user', :controller => 'web', :action => "sign_in_user"
```

I am using Mac OS and Mozilla browser 18.02 AJAX Call is not working. but if i am checking with windows/unix mozilla its working.

I am getting this URL localhost:3000/web/sign_in_user in Address bar and ActionView::MissingTemplate in web # sign_in_user

Comment: Help Required Please ...

Comment: Please post your `routes.rb`for the webcontroller

Comment: @crispychicken get '/web/sign_in_user', :controller => 'web', :action => "sign_in_user"

Comment: Is there an error output in the firefox console? Also try to update Firefox and clear the cache!

Comment: No Error on Console, It should work in all the versions, Right, cache!  Cleared

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't solve the problem but let's try to find the solution step by step:

Make the following changes

**routes.rb:**

```
get '/web/sign_in_user', to: 'web#sign_in_user", as: "sign_in"
```

Let's remove any unnecessary attributes, just to look for the error:
**_header.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", sign_in_path, :remote => true %>
```